# Show that $G$ is a basis of group ring $RG$ over $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

Show that $G$ is a basis of group ring $RG$ over $R$.

**Comments:** That $G$ is through direct generator, if $\alpha \in RG$ then $\alpha = \sum_{g \in G} a_gg$.

I am not able to show that $RG$ is a linearly independent set.

The definition for group ring is: the set $RG$, whose elements are $\alpha = \sum_{g \in G} a_gg$ and this set is a ring defining

$$\sum_{g \in G}a_gg + \sum_{g \in G}b_gg = \sum_{g \in G}(a_g+b_g)g$$
$$(\sum_{g \in G}a_gg)(\sum_{h \in G}b_hh) = \sum_{g,h \in G}(a_gb_h)(gh)$$

The set is a $R-$ module defining

$$\lambda (\sum_{g \in G}a_gg)= \sum_{g \in G}(\lambda a_g)g$$ for $\lambda \in R.$

Comment: A very popular definition of $RG$ includes the fact that $G$ is a basis for it. What definition are you using? Secondly, why would you be trying to show $RG$ is linearly independent? You are trying to show $G$ is linearly independent...

Comment: Is a group ring the same as a group algebra? If so, then as @rschwieb said, I believe the elements of $G$ are assumed to be a basis by definition, and are therefore linearly independent.

Comment: I want to prove that is a basis for $RG$ as $R-$module.

Comment: The definition you are using uses *formal linear combinations*, which amounts to saying that each linear combination is unique. That amounts to declaring that the elements are linearly independent in the definition of the algebra. Nothing needs to be proved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*By definition*, $RG$ is the $R$-module *freely* generated by the set $G$, which means that *by construction* $G$ is a basis of $RG$.